# Can't access to wsdl resource with basic auth from android: ksoap2-android

Tags: android, wsdl, http-authentication, android-ksoap2

I have a problem when access to WSDL resource with basic authentication from android.

Code:

```
package ru.itgorod.test.wsdl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.ksoap2.HeaderProperty;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WSDLTestActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.example.ru/lecompre";
    private static final String URL="http://10.0.0.233/lecompre/ws/lecompre?wsdl"; 
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetGoodsList";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION =  "http://www.example.ru/lecompre/GetGoodsList";   

    private static final String USERNAME = "WS";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";

    private TextView txt;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        Log.i("wsdl", "1");

        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        StringBuffer auth = new StringBuffer(USERNAME);
        auth.append(':').append(PASSWORD);
        byte[] raw = auth.toString().getBytes();
        auth.setLength(0);
        auth.append("Basic ");
        org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode(raw, 0, raw.length, auth);
        List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
        headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", auth.toString())); // "Basic V1M6"));

        try {
            Log.i("wsdl", "2");
            Object response = androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headers); // I got an XmlPullParserException here
            Log.i("wsdl", "3");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            txt.setText("IOException");
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            txt.setText("XmlPullParserException");
        }

        SoapObject result = null;
        try {
            Log.i("wsdl", "4"); 
            result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); 
            Log.i("wsdl", result.toString());
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            txt.setText("SoapFault");
        }                    
    }
}
```

On androidHTTPTransport.call() I got an exception. Server returns an answer "Access is denied". But as I can see in debug androidHTTPTransport.connection.connection.reqHeader.props "autorization" header is already here: [user-agent, kSOAP/2.0, content-type, text/xml, connection, close, content-length, 330, authorization, Basic V1M6]
But in resHeader I got "HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required".

When I trying to open URL in browser - it works fine, but it use GET method with the same "Authorization: Basic V1M6" header.

Can anybody explain where I'm wrong in my code?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**. I found why it happend. ksoap2 transport gives (via HttpURLConnection class) to server http headers in small letters, but server (sometimes) expect each of it with capital initial letter. And I can't understand (can't find in source codes) why and where HttpURLConnection makes it small.

**UPDATE 2**. After my investigation I can assert that this problem concern to core Android libs on version 2.2 (and, may be, older) but not to ksoap2-android itself.
Android 2.3 have no this issue - it send headers in needed case, and also have [Authenticator class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Authenticator.html) worked (see HTTP Authentication section of [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) at Android Developers) which prevent from using workaround methods like used in the code above for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my investigation I can assert that this problem concern to core Android libs of version 2.2 (and, may be, older) but not to ksoap2-android itself. Android 2.3 have no this issue - it send headers in needed case, and also have [Authenticator class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Authenticator.html) worked (see HTTP Authentication section of [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) at Android Developers) which prevent from using workaround methods like used in the code above for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

you got an XmlPullParserException because may be you are using earlier version, please switch ksoap's 2.5.7 version and will not get this kind of exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in [ksoap2 coding tips&tricks](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#Using_Basic_Authentication). 
It says you should use "use the class HttpTransportBasicAuth from the extras package".

Answer (score -1):

I change api version 8 to 10, solved this problem.

AndroidManifest.xml:

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="10"   />`